# Remove values with numbers from array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, opencart

I have an array of categories getting values from database

```
<?php foreach ($category_1['children'] as $category_2) { ?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $category_2['href']; ?>">
<?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

It returns values like

`8.5" x 14" (Tri-Fold)
8.5" x 2.75"
8.5" x 3.667" (1/3 Page)
8.5" x 5.5"
8.5" x 5.5" (1/2 Page)
80lb gloss book, 16 Page Wall Calendar
9" x 12" Envelope
9" x 14.5"
Booklets/Catalogs
Bookmarks
Brochures
Business Cards
Calendars`

The problem is that I want to remove the values which have numbers in it and display the values with names only.
For eg.

`Booklets/Catalogs
Bookmarks
Brochures
Business Cards
Calendars`

So how can I remove the values with numbers from the array. Can it be done with the `array_filter` using wildcard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution using `array_filter` and `preg_match` functions:

```
...

$category_1['children'] = array_filter($category_1['children'], function($v){
    return !preg_match("/\d/", $v["name"]);
});
// now the $category_1['children'] array contains only items with needed "names"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following code and it works. It loops through the array with a for loop and when it finds a row with an `href` that's not empty it removes the element from array. You can see bellow that I have created the array `$category_1['children']` :

```
<?php


$category_1['children'] = array(
  array('href' => 'j', 'name' => 'aa'),
  array('href' => '', 'name' => 'bb'),
  array('href' => 'j', 'name' => 'aa'),
  array('href' => 'l', 'name' => 'aaas'),
  array('href' => '', 'name' => 'aa'),
  array('href' => '', 'name' => 'cc')
);
```

Now time to sort it out :

```
$array = $category_1['children'];
for ($i=0; $i < count($category_1['children']); $i++) {
  if($category_1['children'][$i]['href'] != null) {
    unset($category_1['children'][$i]);
  }
}
```

Verify result :

```
print_r($category_1['children']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `array_filter()` is the solution.

```
$new_array = array_filder($category_1['children'], function ($element) {
    return !preg_match("~[0-9]~", $element['name'])
}
```

I didn't test it, but it should work.

Do this *before* the `foreach()` and check values with a `die(var_dump($new_array))`;

**// Edit**
The solution provided by @romanperekhrest is a better `preg_match`, anyway if you don't want to use regular expressions, an alternative would be

```
!strpbrk($element, '1234567890')
```

*It's obviously intended inside the closure*.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($category_1['children'] as $category_2) { 
        $str = $category_2['name'];
         preg_match('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
        if(empty($matches))){
        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $category_2['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></a>
    <?php } 
        }?>
```

preg match checks for numeric value in category name and if there is no numeric data, displays the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way:

```
<?php foreach ($category_1['children'] as $category_2) { ?>

<?php if(1 !== preg_match('~[0-9]~', $category_2['name'])){ ?>

  <li><a href="<?php echo $category_2['href']; ?>">

      <?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></a></li>

<?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use regex `'/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/'` and put a check on it: e.g.

```
<?php foreach ($category_1['children'] as $category_2) {

  if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/', category_2['name'])) {?>

   <li><a href="<?php echo $category_2['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></a></li>

  <?php }

} ?>
```